# How to find out if popupState from Material UI is opened

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, popup, popover

I'm using PopupState / [Popover](https://material-ui.com/components/popover/) in order to build a component, it works fine but I need to change the icon, when the popup is opened or closed it should show a different icon.

This is my component:

```
  <PopupState variant="popover" popupId="demo-popup-popover">
    {(popupState) => (
      <div className="details-button">
        <Button {...bindTrigger(popupState)}>
          click me!
          <span className="caret-down"></span> // <-- here is the icon, caret-down
        </Button>
        <Popover
          className="popover-container"
          {...bindPopover(popupState)}
          anchorOrigin={{
            vertical: 'bottom',
            horizontal: 'center'
          }}
          transformOrigin={{
            vertical: 'top',
            horizontal: 'center'
          }}>
          <Box>
            <Typography onClick={openModal}>
              <span className="icon-16-bulletedList-mono"></span>
              create
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </Popover>
      </div>
    )}
  </PopupState>
```

As it can be seen, there is a span with a caret inside, the caret should be `caret-down` when the popup is closed and `caret-up` when it is opened.

Is there a way to find out this information?

A log was added to print the popupState variable but it doesn't have useful information:

```
anchorEl: button.MuiButtonBase-root.MuiButton-root.MuiButton-text
close: ƒ ()
disableAutoFocus: false
isOpen: false
onMouseLeave: ƒ (e)
open: ƒ (e)
popupId: "demo-popup-popover"
setAnchorEl: ƒ (e)
setAnchorElUsed: false
setOpen: ƒ (e,t)
toggle: ƒ (e)
variant: "popover"
_childPopupState: null
_setChildPopupState: ƒ (e)
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: You need use your anchorEl state. Like : Boolean(anchorEl)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your open state is but I assume it's anchorEl.

```
<span className={Boolean(anchorEl) ? "caret-up" : "caret-down"}></span>
```

Comment: Do you want to say like this: `{Boolean(popupState.anchorEl) ? "caret-up" : "caret-down"}></span>`?

Comment: Well I can't see anchorEl in your popupState log it's probably popupState.isOpen then.